# Subscriber RetrieveRequest Getting Attributes by name with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In an AMPscript landing page, I am doing a retrieverequest getting a subscriber by subscriberkey and I need to be able to access the Subscriber's Attributes by name. So far, I can successfully get an array of Attributes for my subscriber with this command:

```
SET @subAtts = FIELD(ROW(@mySubs,1),"Attributes")
```

And I can do the following to get the value of attributes, in this case First Name, from the Subscriber Attributes with this:

```
SET @att = ROW(@subAtts,2)
SET @myFirstName = Field(@att, 'Value')
```

But doing it this way, I have to find the index for some 35 different Attributes. Is there any way to get the attribute value by attribute name such as:

```
SET @myFirstName = SOMECOOLFUNCTION(@subAtts,"First Name")
```

Would appreciate any guidance here. Thanks

wck

Answer (score 1):

In AMPScript, you would have to iterate the array to find your attribute and value

```
FOR @i = RowCount(@subAtts) DOWNTO 1 DO

  SET @att = Row(@subAtts, @i)
  SET @att_name = Field(@att,'Name')
  SET @att_val = Field(@att,'Value')

  IF @att_name == "First Name" THEN
    SET @firstName = @att_val
  ELSEIF @att_name == "Last Name" THEN
    SET @LastName = @att_val    
  ENDIF

NEXT @i
```

if you use server-side JavaScript then you could do something similar to this:

```
<script runat='server'>
  Platform.Load('Core','1');
  var subObj = Subscriber.Init(myEmailAddress);
  var attributes = subObj.Attributes.Retrieve();
  var myAttributes = {};

  for(var a in attributes){
    myAttributes[attributes[a].Name] = attributes[a].Value;
  }

</script>

<ctrl:eval>myAttributes['First Name']</ctrl:eval>
```

Helpful link:
[Server-side JavaScript Reference](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/subscriber_server_side_javascript_library)